# Generating a distribution map without x and y from given raster-grid into given polygons

Tags: qgis, polygon, csv, mapping, distribution

I am working on an archaeological map for an excavation. I have given polygons which represent my archaeological layers (SE). Over that I have an grid with 1mx1m from which I have my findings. Each of this gridsquares is identified like a chess board (a1;b1; ...) Also I have different types of material in my findings (ceramics, metal, bone,...). The point is the findings are located to the grid and the layer (SE) where it was found, but has no direct messurement in X and y. I now want to make a distribution map for each of the material groups and or with them all together on one layer. So I will have a map with multiple SEs shown with the amount of material found in each grid per SE.

By now I have drawn all my polygons for the SEs and I have cut them to fit each gridsqare, so that I have a polygon for SE 23 in B1 and C1. If there are more than one polygon from the same SE in one grid sqare I already have merged them to one, so that my single identifier is the combination of SE and Grid name. But when I am trying to connect the attribute table of my polygons and the CSV of my findings it does not work at all.
So can anyone give me a hint how to get the map described above?

I am using Q.GIS 3.12 Bucuresti.
As I wrote I have tried to do a new point layer with a point for each SE-part per square. But I cant do the integration of my findings. So I am asking how my Attributtable should look, when I have as ID the combination of SE and grid name and I have amount and weight per material from 8 different materialtypes which I want to display all together and per materialtype. –

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.  Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works. What GIS software are you using?

Comment: You don't say which GIS system you are using?

Comment: I am using Q.GIS 3.12 Bucuresti.

Comment: As I wrote I have tried to do a new point layer with a point for each SE-part per square. But I cant do the integration of my findings. So I am asking how my Attributtable should look, when I have as ID the combination of SE and grid name and I have amount and weight per material from 8 different materialtypes which I want to display all together and per materialtype.